# Closing iAd Interstitial causes segue

Tags: ios, iad, interstitial, unwind-segue

I have 2 view controllers. A button in ControllerA causes a segue to ControllerB. In ControllerB, I display an interstitial ad after every X number of taps on a button. When the ad shows the iAd test ad, immediately closing the ad by tapping on the "x" on the upper left corner closes that ad, and all is well. But if I interact with the ad by tapping on "Learn More" for example, and then click on the "x", the ad will close then it appears an unwind segue is triggered and you are brought to ControllerA. This happens consistently.

I display the ad using

```
self.requestInterstitialAdPresentation()
```

I tried to catch this with a breakpoint on

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    print ("preparing for segueue")
}
```

but this code never gets reached. My normal unwind segue button does trigger it.

Also, when this occurs, I get this message in the console:

```
Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <ControllerA> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!
```

Any ideas why this is happening?